# Natbib 'undefined control sequence' using \citep

Tags: citing, miktex, natbib

I am using MiKTeX TeXworks on Windows 7 and a `natbib` bibliography style. When I attempt to cite using `\citep` I get the following message:

```
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\omsppl.fd")
! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 ... \citep{Daddz14}
?
```

This is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,natbib,wrapfig}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{multirow,colortbl,longtable}
\newcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}
\begin{document}

\citep{Daddz14}

\bibliographystyle{natbib}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

This is the entry in my `.bib` file:

```
@article{Daddz14,
author={D'Addezio,JM and Bingham,FM},
title={A subtropical {N}orth {A}tlantic regional atmospheric moisture 
budget},
journal=jgr_o,
volume={119},
number={12},
pages={8731-8748},
year={2014}}
```

It works absolutely fine when I use `\cite` but none of the other citation commands seem to work either e.g. `\citealp` or `\citet`. I've recently had no trouble with `\citep` and `natbib` on the same computer using MiKTeX so I'm wondering if it might have something to do with the book document class (previously I'd used article). The `omsppl.fd` file might be important too, but I have no idea what that is! I have also seen a few other questions similar to this but none of the solutions have helped.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I get `Command \refname already defined` and `I couldn't open style file natbib.bst` from BibTeX, to the best of my knowledge there is no `natbib.bst` you will have to use a real `natbib` style such as `plainnat`.

Comment: `natbib.bst` does exist: http://www.aisb.org.uk/publications/aisbj/forms/natbib.bst and changing the `\bilbiographystyle` to `plainnat` hasn't helped either unfortunately.

Comment: natbib.bst was available link: http://www.aisb.org.uk/publications/aisbj/forms/natbib.bst but I am not sure whether this is latest...

Comment: Well, `natbib.bst` is not on CTAN and certainly not part of the `natbib` package there. In fact your file states `Personal bib style, PWD`, so I assume it is just an unfortunately named personal style that is not on CTAN

Comment: @MadyYuvi That seems to be an 'unofficial' file, it's not on CTAN and marked marked `Personal bib style, PWD`. The `.bst`s that ship with the current CTAN versions of `natbib` don't identify as 'personal' and are all newer that the ominous `natbib.bst`.

Comment: `omsppl.fd` has nothing to do with your problem: it is a `f(ont) d(efinition)` file, in relation with the `palatino` package. However, this package is obsolete, and should be replaced with `newpxtext` and `newpxmath`, which use `TeX Gyre pagella`, a palatino clone.

Answer (score 2):

I've sorted this out now. Thank you to @moewe for pointing me towards the official CTAN `natbib` stuff. It seems that part of my problem is that the `.sty` file was in a different directory from my `.tex` file. My `\bibliographystyle` command did include the path to the directory where `natbib.sty` was stored but that didn't work.Now that I've got all the correct files in the correct place `\citep` is working exactly as it should do.

Thanks to those of you who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any issues in your file, only error I got as `! LaTeX Error: Command \refname already defined`. but that too can fix as by using `\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}`

Comment: When I run that example I don't get any issues either actually (should have tested it first obviously). I will expand the MWE to show all the packages I'm using.